# How to downgrade from websocket to http?

Tags: html, http, websocket

I've been reading abit about html5, websockets and http. I made some simple tests but let's say I want to do this:

1. Browser makes an http connection to a web server
2. Browser then negotiates a web socket connection to the same web server
3. At some point browser wants to talk http again with the web server in the same session

Points 1 and 2 are straightforward. Coming to point 3, is there a standard solution available? I'm guessing that closing a web socket by either side terminates the existing connection right? Can there be a way to perform a "downgrade" from websockets back to http?

I guess what I'm looking for is a standards-based solution but if one doesnt exist, do any frameworks exist that can do the job?

Thanks :o)
Nina

Comment: There's nothing in the specs about downgrading a WebSocket connection, so I guess there are two options: 1) As you suggested, close the WebSocket connection and go back to standard HTTP, or 2) leave the WebSocket connection open, and just use HTTP (e.g., Ajax) instead, even though the WebSocket connection is still open.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Usually a WebSocket connection is established on a new TCP connection after the page has loaded.

Comment: @HartleySan from your comments I'm guessing your option 1 means to open a new http connection, right? Regarding your option 2, can all webservers that support websockets do that? (eg Apache) So all I have to do to resume http connection is just to start sending http requests within the web socket connection after the tcp exchange is completed?

Comment: @Philipp I'm looking at other ways to do redirections etc. I mean in the midst of an http session the web browser might want to initiate some streaming video using websockets, but when that is over, to go back to just "plain" http connection with the webserver but within the same session so the browser does not need to reauthenticate itself.. that's just one example, but I hope that made some sense :-)

Comment: @Nina, I do agree with Philipp in that once you have a WebSocket connection established, it makes the most sense to simply use that for just about everything because it is much more efficient and faster than regular HTTP requests. Anyway, in order to send client requests via a WebSocket connection, after establishing the connection and performing a valid handshake, you have to use the send method of the WebSocket object. By that rationale, simply send data to the server without using the send method, and the data will be sent by regular HTTP by default. That's what I was eluding to.